# Recursive look up parent entity's value

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a category entity which uses a hierarchical structure, each entity can have a parent or children.

The entity holds "enabled" value, if marked as false, all child entities should be marked as "false" too.

I created a simple recursion method as below to achieve this, but it gives me very strange results (by strange I mean the current entity always returns the correct value for "enabled" however, all parent entities default to "false"

Here is the code snippet:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "category")
@SQLDelete(sql ="UPDATE category SET active = 0 WHERE pk = ? AND version = ?")
@Where(clause = "active = 1")
public class CategoryEntity extends AbstractEntity{


    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2285380147654080016L;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_category")
    private CategoryEntity parentCategory;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="parentCategory", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<CategoryEntity> childCategories = new ArrayList<CategoryEntity>();

    @Column(name = "source_id", unique=true)
    private String sourceId;

    @Column(name = "enabled", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "boolean default true")
    private boolean enabled;

    public CategoryEntity getParentCategory() {
        return parentCategory;
    }

    public void setParentCategory(CategoryEntity parentCategory) {
        this.parentCategory = parentCategory;
    }

    public List<CategoryEntity> getChildCategories() {
        return childCategories;
    }

    public void setChildCategories(List<CategoryEntity> childCategories) {
        this.childCategories = childCategories;
    }

    public boolean getEnabled() {
        return isEnabled(this);
    }

    private boolean isEnabled(CategoryEntity cat){
        if(cat != null && cat.enabled){
            if(cat.getParentCategory() == null) return true;
            return isEnabled(cat.getParentCategory());
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }
```

}

The culprit is the **isEnabled()** method, hopefully you guys can help here? Maybe a better question would be, whether this is even legal in JPA?

Comment: call it something else because isEnabled is still java bean convention for boolean and it might be confusing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the reason behind that is that you use the 'enabled' property directly in the parent objects. It is lazy loaded object and it is not initialized yet (when you access the parent). And when you access that parent category object it is basically a proxy to the object with all primitives set to their default values (for enabled it would be false).

Try changing it to:

```
public boolean getEnabled() {
    return this.enabled;
}
public boolean getCalculatedEnabled() {
    return getCalculatedEnabled(this);
}

private boolean getCalculatedEnabled(CategoryEntity cat){
    if(cat != null && cat.getEnabled()){  //this will trigger the lazy initialization of the object
        if(cat.getParentCategory() == null) return true;
        return getCalculatedEnabled(cat.getParentCategory());
    }
    return false;
}
```

You will have two fields like (enabled and calculatedEnabled) but still it won't break the java bean convention and it will hopefully work ;)

Comment: seems that it needed the default getter to lazily initialise, otherwise, it was pulling default boolean value which was "false"

Answer (score 0):

In your method `isEnabled` your are returning `true` if the entity has a parent, else `false`. Hence all children will be `true` and the ones without parent will be `false`.